# Centering an image as canvas on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=1100)
image = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\name\\Pictures\\picture.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="center", image=image)
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas.pack()
```

I have tried making an image the canvas for my GUI and it will not center it self on the application...I've tried all types of functions like relative X and Y to the canvas and anchoring but I can't seem to get it to center it self..

Comment: `canvas.create_image(550, 200, image=image)` and also remove `canvas.place(...)` because you have called `canvas.pack()` later which will override `canvas.place(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `create_image(x,y,...)` to specify the coordinates for the middle of the canvas. The centre is the height/width divided by two.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 1100
canvas = Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
image = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\User\MyImage.png")
canvas.create_image(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, anchor="center", image=image)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried using this and the image is very zoomed in, is there a function where I can just make the image fit the canvas size or even a zoom out function?

Comment: You can zoom(make bigger) or subsample(make smaller) with PhotoImage. For example `image = image.subsample(2)` will make the image twice as small. It doesn't give much control though and you'd be better resizing the image in an external program unless you want to use Python Imaging Library (PIL) to resize it instead. That'd be a separate question though

Comment: Note that using the code I provided in my answer, won't have `zoomed` the image, the image is just too big for your canvas.

Comment: Yeah I just realized, went and found a smaller image and just adjusted canvas size to fit the needs.